# Direct links to Stack Exchange profile subtabs look bad

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, stackexchange.com, tabs

In a StackExchange.com profile, you can directly link to a tab like [Favorites](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=favorites) just fine. But when you try to link to the [votes subtab](https://stackexchange.com/users/favorites/-1?page=1&sort=votes) under that, it doesn't look right because it's not the entire page (most of the navigation is missing, such as the top bar) and nothing is stylized:

> [image: question that is not styled]

This also happens with the [activity](https://stackexchange.com/users/7562599/laurel?tab=activity) subtabs. Note that clicking them is OK (and the URL doesn't actually change), but opening the link in a new window will show this bug.

Comment: This happens occasionally when I hit a Too Many Requests ban.

Comment: @Sonic no, it happen always. They're using AJAX to parse the response. This used to be the case in all user profiles, think it was changed when they were last re-designed few years ago.